# Behaviour of templated class wrapping a member function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wrapper

I have a function of a class I would like to iteratively call inside a loop, and while the loop is fixed, I want to be able to provide different functions (from the given object). To approach this, I created a templated struct `MyWrapper` to take the object whose function I want to call, the function itself, and data for which to evaluate the function. (In that sense, the member function will always have the same signature)

What I found though, was that using a member function pointer incurs a huge performance cost, even though at compile time, I know the function I want to call. So I was messing around to try and fix this, and (while I'm still unclear why the first situation happens), I've experienced another interesting behaviour.

In the following situation, *every* call to the wrapper function `MyWrapper::eval` will actually attempt to copy my whole `Grid` object into the parameter to the given function it has to wrap, `f`, even though the call to `MyEquation::eval` will know not to copy it every time (because of optimization).

```cpp
template<typename T>
double neighbour_average(T *v, int n)
{
    return v[-n] + v[n] - 2 * v[0];
}

template<typename T>
struct MyEquation
{
    T constant;
    int n;
    T eval(Grid<T, 2> v, int i)
    {
        return rand() / RAND_MAX + neighbour_average(v.values + i, n) + constant;
    }
};


template<typename T, typename R, typename A>
struct MyWrapper
{
    MyWrapper(T &t, R(T::*f)(A, int), A a) : t{ t }, f{ f }, a{ a } {}
    auto eval(int i)
    {
        return (t.*f)(a, i);
    }

protected:
    A a;
    T &t;
    R(T::*f)(A, int);
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (iter_type i = 0; i < config().len_; ++i)
    {
        op.values[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    double constant = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    int n = 2;
    int test_len = 100'000, 
    int test_run = 100'000'000;

    Grid<double, 2> arr(100, 1000);
    MyEquation<double> eq{ constant, n };
    MyWrapper weq(eq, &MyEquation<double>::eval, arr); // I'm wrapping what I want to do

    {
        // Time t0("wrapper thing");
        for (int i = 0; i < test_run; ++i)
        {
            arr.values[n + i % (test_len - n)] += weq.eval(n + i % (test_len - n)); // a call to the wrapping class to evaluate
        }
    }
    {
        // Time t0("regular thing");
        for (int i = 0; i < test_run; ++i)
        {
            arr.values[n + i % (test_len - n)] += rand() / RAND_MAX + neighbour_average(arr.values + n + i % (test_len - n), n) + constant; // a usage of the neighbour function without the wrapping call
        }
    }

    {
        // Time t0("function thing");
        for (int i = 0; i < test_run; ++i)
        {
            arr.values[n + i % (test_len - n)] += eq.eval(arr, n + i % (test_len - n)); // raw evaluation of my equation
        }
    }

}
```

Some context:

`Grid` is just a glorified dynamic array `Grid::values` with a few helper functions.

I've retained some of the (seemingly unnecessary) templates to my function and object, because it closely parallels how my code is actually set up.

The `Time` class will give me the duration of the object lifetime, so its a quick and dirty way of measuring certain blocks of code.

So anyways...

If the following code is changed so the signature of the function taken by `MyWrapper` is `R(T::*f)(A&, int)`, then the execution time of `MyWrapper::eval` will be almost identical to the other calls (which is what I want anyways).

Why doesn't the compiler (msvc 2017) know it should treat the call `weq.eval(n)` (and consequently `(t.*f)(a, n)`) the with the same optimization considerations way as the direct evaluation, if the signature and function is given at compile time?

Comment: Please clarify what results you get for your benchmarks. It's not clear which (ones?) of the three you are referring to as "direct calls" or "regular function call".

Comment: I apologize I was unclear, I didnt mean to compare benchmarks, I was providing context as to what led me to my question. I left in the benchmarks because they are a transparent way to see what I'm doing, but timings dont matter. For direct call, I meant without using the `MyWrapper`.

Comment: I clarified my question to address the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function parameter is its own variable, which gets initialized from a function call argument.  So when a function argument in the calling function is an lvalue such as the name of an object previously defined, and the function parameter is an object type, not a reference type, the parameter and the argument are two different objects.  If the parameter has a class type, this means a constructor for that type has to be executed (unless the initialization is an aggregate initialization from a `{}` initializer list).

In other words, every call to

```
T eval(Grid<T, 2> v, int i);
```

needs to create a new `Grid<T, 2>` object called `v`, whether it's called via function pointer or by the member name `eval`.

But in many cases, initialization of a reference doesn't create a new object. It appears your `eval` doesn't need to modify `v` or the `MyEquation`, so it would be better to declare that `eval` as:

```
T eval(const Grid<T, 2> &v, int i) const;
```

This would mean the function pointer in `Wrapper` needs to be `R (T::*f)(const A&, int) const`.

But another change you might want to make, especially since `Wrapper` is already a template: Just make the function used a generic type, so that it can hold non-member function pointers, wrappers to member function pointers with any signature, lambdas, or any other class type with an `operator()` member.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename F, typename A>
struct MyWrapper
{
    MyWrapper(F f, A a) : f{ std::move(f) }, a{ std::move(a) } {}
    auto eval(int i)
    {
        return f(a, i);
    }

protected:
    A a;
    F f;
};
```

Then two ways to create your `Wrapper weq;` are:

```
Wrapper weq([&eq](const auto &arr, int i) {
    return eq.eval(arr, i);
}, arr);
```

or (requires `#include <functional>`):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
Wrapper weq(
    std::bind(std::mem_fn(&MyEquation<double>::eval), _1, _2),
    arr);
```

Comment: Then, due to the indirection of having to call `MyEquation::eval` from `MyWrapper::eval`, is it the case that the optimization won't know to elide the copy (if I've used that term correctly)? Would you be able to add that to your answer? You've addressed everything else I was wondering about!

Comment: It looks like this is relevant to my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259466/do-compilers-optimize-away-calls-to-trivial-functions-made-through-pointers